# Django extend django-cms view

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I am using django-cms. My goal is to get data from form which is in index page. **Problem is, i don't have access to this view.** So in base.html i have this:

```
<form method="get" action="">
    <input type="text" name="q">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

I need based on user input make search. In my urls.py there is line `url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),` which renders index page. I could accomplish that if i had access to that view, but i don't. Is there someting i can do?

Answer (score 0):

To do something like that you need to create an application & hook it into django-cms.

For a search app, there is already a widely used application from the developers of django-cms; [Aldryn Search](https://github.com/aldryn/aldryn-search)

Check out the docs for [Apphooks](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/how_to/apphooks.html) as well, because you can tie any django app into django-cms. You basically create a page from which the app is served so that defines the URL on the site where your application's URLs will be used.

Equally you could hard-code URLs into your project's `urls.py` and then create a form in your index.html that posted to a URL you've hardcoded in to the project. But I'd avoid that, and read up on app hooks.

Comment: @Mažas did this help?